# WebException error from HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am getting an error like this when I try to get the HttpWebResponse.Can anyone tell me the possible reason for this type of exception?

A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Is this related to IIS or any other server issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is part of the standard ASP.NET processing pipeline.  A first chance exception is an exception that is often and handled by a try / catch block.  here are some older articles that explains first chance exceptions

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/07/12/438061.aspx
https://support.microsoft.com/kb/105675

Here is some additional information on how to debug/stop at first chance exceptions

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/07/18/440150.aspx

Comment: I am working on VS 2012 with .NET framework 4.5.I cant find the Break into debugger option in it

Comment: @abi_anarchy95 once you start debugging, click on the debug menu, select exceptions... when the Exception dialog is displayed, click all of the checkboxes under the thrown column.

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance in HttpWebRequest class. Like

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two");
request.Method = "POST";
```

and add Method function to it. Whe you miss Method function, you may get WebException error sometimes. Give a try.